# Evaluating $\int_0^1dx\int_x^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{y\,dy}{(1+xy)^2(1+y^2)}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Evaluate the integral (change of order of integration may be useful):$$\int_0^1dx\int_x^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{y\,dy}{(1+xy)^2(1+y^2)}$$

I searched the region, I got this graph

[image]

But, can't identify the region exactly. In fact, the lower bound of y and upper bound does not match to a region. I can be wrong. Please give any hints or you can add a solution.

Comment: The region of integration consists of points $(x,y)$ such that $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $x\leq y\leq \frac{1}{x}$. You should be able to identify this region in your plot. (You need to account for the bounds on both $y$ and $x$ to get a well-defined region.)

Comment: @halrankard I think the region is a triangle where the lower bound is y=0 and upper bound is y=x. But, I can't understand why there is $y=\frac1x$

Comment: The point $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$ is in the triangular region you've described. But this point does not satisfy $x\leq y\leq \frac{1}{x}$ which is enforced by the bounds on the inner integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region of interest is bounded between the y-axis, the line $y=x$, and the line $y=\frac{1}{x}$, where $0<x<1$.  Maybe this image will help you visualize it better:

[image: Region]

To change the order of integration, first notice that we need to split the region into two along the line $y=1$ because of the shape of the region.
Consider the first region $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq y$ and the second region $1 \leq y < \infty$ and $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{y}$.  These two regions together are equal to the original region.

[image: Region 2]
Rewrite your integral as follows:
$$\int_0^1 \int_x^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{y}{{(1+xy)}^2{(1+y^2)}} \; dy \; dx=\int_0^1 \int_0^{y} \frac{y}{{(1+xy)}^2{(1+y^2)}} \; dx \; dy + \int_1^{\infty} \int_0^{\frac{1}{y}} \frac{y}{{(1+xy)}^2{(1+y^2)}} \; dx \; dy$$
$$=\int_0^1 -\frac{1}{{(1+y^2)}^2} + \frac{1}{1+y^2}\; dy+ \frac{1}{2} \int_1^{\infty}  \frac{1}{1+y^2} \; dy$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{8}=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: Great!! You did great

Comment: But, can you please tell me from which website you took this screenshot?

Comment: @AnkitaPal Desmos

Comment: Ok, thank you